# How to fix unresponsive filesystem without rebooting?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, ssh, open-source

I tried to mount an external storage device in MacOS 12.3.1 using `sshfs`, but I had to stop this process in the middle of whatever it is doing.

Now, when I do a `ls -l` in the file system it hangs for minutes. There is no output in a terminal using `ls -l`.

I could fix that rebooting the device - but is there ANY *possibility* to fix this issue without rebooting the device (MAcBook Air) all the time?

I still can do `ls` in other folders.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to stop navigating in that folder path and try to `umount` it. Even a `df` may put you in timeout mode.

If you think your ssh connection is stale, you could look at ServerAliveInterval (check your FAQ for your version of sshfs you chose for syntax)

The delays baked into sshfs to make it handle long network delays is the ultimate root cause here if ssh stays connected. Going forward, you may want to use a File Provider extension which allows your Mac to always stay fast and catch up to external storage when the network can sync data asyncronously.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider