# Where does APFS hide the resource forks and/or persistent Finder data?

Tags: finder, apfs, macos

Opening a directory in Finder used to create a .DS_Store in the directory.  But I just opened one today and that file was not created.  However, it did add eight kilobytes to the size of the directory.

And if I copy or move `filename` from APFS into a remote Debian directory mounted by SSHFS, a `._filename` appears there.

But when looking here for ..namedfork or /rsrc or ..namedfork/rsrc, I find nothing.

Comment: Isn’t [sshfs a local cache that tries to run ftp regularly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440757/5472) to sync the two “file systems”? My recollection is it makes the illusion of an external filesystem locally. I’m assuming all is fine when you copy from one local APFS to another.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works.  I know that it also requires MacFUSE.  But something on this end knows it's not Mac and creates the ._filename which is not needed in any of the files I am putting there.  (In my websites on Apache)